# JavaCC choice conflict warning

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc, ambiguity

I'm having a singular issue with JavaCC at the moment.  I have my grammar defined, the language is LL(1) and all Left Recursion has been removed.  I'm getting a choice conflict error (dumped below).  I believe it is caused by the line `expr2()` line calling itself and causing a conflict.  I'm honestly completely stumped.  I don't even know how to go about fixing the problem.

Here's the snippet of code generating the warning:

```
void expr() : {}
{
  <LBRAC> arg_list() <RBRAC> expression2()
}

void expr2() : {}
{
  section() (<SUB>|<ADD>|<MUL>|<DIV>|<MOD> section())* expr2()
  | {}
}

void section() : {}
{
  <IDENTIFIER> | <TRUE> | <FALSE> | <REAL> | (<ADD> | <SUB>) section() | expr()
}
```

And the warning is:

```
Warning: 
Choice conflict in (...)* construct at line 233, column 14.
     Expansion nested within construct and expansion following construct
     have common prefixes, one of which is: "-"
     Consider using a lookahead of 2 or more for nested expansion.
Parser generated with 0 errors and 1 warnings.
```

Where line 233 corrisponds to first line in expr2()

Comment: Consider "2 + 2". The "+" is the <ADD> at expr2() or <ADD> at section()?

Comment: I can remove the Add/Sub commands from section() and it still causes the same issue.  I understand what you mean though, but that doesn't appear to be causing the problem.

Comment: What Juan said is entirely correct. But changing `(<ADD> | <SUB>) section()`to `section()` introduces a new problem. Try changing the first line in the body of `expr2` to either `section() (<MUL>|<DIV>|<MOD> section())* expr2()` or `section() ((<MUL>|<DIV>|<MOD>) section())* expr2()` depending on what you actually want. If that doesn't work, ask a new question. Juan has answered this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Juan Lopes wrote:

> Consider "2 + 2". The "+" is the `<ADD>` at `expr2()` or`<ADD>` at `section()`?

The OP replied:

> I can remove the Add/Sub commands from `section()` and it still causes the same issue. I understand what you mean though, but that doesn't appear to be causing the problem.

@Theodore Norvell wrote:

> What Juan said is entirely correct. But changing `(<ADD> | <SUB>) section()` to `section()` introduces a new problem. Try changing the first line in the body of `expr2` to either `section() (<MUL>|<DIV>|<MOD> section())* expr2()` or `section() ((<MUL>|<DIV>|<MOD>) section())* expr2()` depending on what you actually want. If that doesn't work, ask a new question. Juan has answered this one.

Comment: ([Question was answered in the comments; these converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))